# How to bind a property to properties of objects in a list property?

Tags: java, javafx

I have these classes:

```
class Parent {

    BooleanProperty total = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    SimpleListProperty<Child> children = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
}

class Child {

    BooleanProperty single = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
}
```

What I want is that `total` will be false if and only if all of the children's `single`s are false. In other words that if and only if there is one child with `single` as true then `total` is true.

I came up with this binding

```
total.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
    return children.stream().filter(c -> c.isSingle()).findAny().isPresent();
}, children.stream().map(c -> c.single).collect(Collectors.toCollection(FXCollections::observableArrayList))));
```

Is this the best way?

Also should i make `total` read only because writing to a bound property will throw an exception?

Comment: Will the list change after the binding is created?

Comment: @James_D yes. i'm reading your answer right now and it's certainly a good point i didn't know about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible problem with binding explicitly to every child's `single` property, is that these bindings are made when the `total.bind(...)` statement is invoked. Consequently, if new `Child` objects are *subsequently* added to the list, those child's `single` properties will not be observed and the binding will not be invalidated if they change. Similarly, if a child is removed from the list, its `single` property will not be unbound.

As an alternative, you can create the list with an [extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-). Note that for most use cases, you have no need for a `ListProperty`: just using an `ObservableList` directly is sufficient. So you can just do

```
ObservableList<Child> children = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(c -> new Observable[]{c.singleProperty()});
```

This list will now fire update notifications (and become invalid) if any of the elements `single` properties are invalidated (as well as when elements are added to and from the list). In other words, the list itself observes each child's `single` property, and the list becomes invalid (causing anything bound to it to become invalid) if any of the children's `single` properties become invalid. The list also makes sure it observes new children's `single` properties when they are added to the list, and stops observing them when children are removed from the list.

Then you just need

```
total.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
    children.stream().anyMatch(Child::isSingle), children);
```

Finally, consider using a `ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper` in order to expose the property as read only. Here's a properly-encapsulated version of the whole thing:

```
public class Parent {

    private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper total = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper();
    private ObservableList<Child> children = 
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(c -> new Observable[] {c.singleProperty()});

    public Parent() {
        total.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> 
            children.stream().anyMatch(Child::isSingle), children);
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty totalProperty() {
        return total.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public ObservableList<Child> getChildren() {
        return children ;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Child {
    private final BooleanProperty single = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public BooleanProperty singleProperty() {
        return single ;
    }

    public final boolean isSingle() {
        return singleProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setSingle(boolean single) {
        singleProperty().set(single);
    }
}
```

Comment: so the way this works is that a change in a child's `single` property causes the list to property to "fire an update event" to all its observers (bound properties)? when i list the dependency as `children` then the bound property will be updated either if `children` itself changes (the list is replaced) or if any of the observables listed in the constructor change?

Comment: Well... hmm. It will only work if the new list has an extractor attached, which obviously might be a problem. As long as the list has an extractor, then the list itself observes the properties returned by the extractor, and becomes invalid if any of the properties become invalid. Do you really need the children list to be mutable (i.e. a `setChildren()` method); for most use cases it's sufficient to have an immutable (but modifiable) list (i.e. no `setChildren()` method but a `getChildren()` method, so you can do `getChildren().setAll(...)`, for example).

Comment: no, `children` itself won't be replaced and there is no `setChildren`. i was asking to learn about bindings - what are the conditions under which the binding will update.

Comment: If there's no `setChildren()`, then you don't need a `ListProperty`; just use an `ObservableList<Child>` directly. Let me update...

Comment: also on the topic of not changing the list reference: not having `setChildren` is not enough i think since you can call `childrenProperty` and set it from there. so the `children` property also needs to be read-only? or will that not allow to modify the list's contents?

Comment: @Mark just use a `ObservableList` property with only a getter (Like e.g. [`Pane.getChildren()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html#getChildren--)).

Comment: Well you also failed to make anything private, so you could also do obnoxious things like `parent.children = FXCollection.observableArrayList()`, or `child.single = new SimpleBooleanProperty()`, which would entirely screw things up... See update

Comment: then an observable list will function like a read-only list property because in both cases i don't allow changing the list itself but only modifying it? i'm confused :(

Comment: More or less, yes. Typically a read-only property can't be changed externally, but can be changed internally (e.g. the total property behaves like this). Here, you're unlikely to even change the list itself internally, so the list reference can be `final`, and doesn't need to be wrapped in a property at all.